# Estimating the # of Principal components based on variance explained

Tags: r, regression, pca

I am running PCA on a dataset with dimensions 1460(n) * 307(p). Upon running PCA, I obtain the below plot of variance explained and the number of components. I am trying to estimate the number of PCs to select for my training dataset.

Based on the plot below, It appears that around 75% of the variance is explained/captured by 50 PCs. So, selecting 50 PCs is a reasonable estimate.

How would you interpret the below plot and estimate # of PCs to select?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: http://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/17/topic-library/modeling-statistics/multivariate/principal-components-and-factor-analysis/number-of-principal-components/

Comment: You choose your desired percentage (80%, 90%). You use it to select your components.

Comment: @Student T yeah - the scree plot shows a steep curve until like ~20 PCs and then it's horizontal line from then on.

Comment: Answers in this post go into detail on methods for appropriately selecting the number of components. The Valle paper referred to is a very good introduction to this topic: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100143/what-are-good-metrics-to-assess-the-quality-of-a-pca-fit-in-order-to-select-the/100144#100144